# Segmentation fault in fgets() - C language

Tags: c, stream, segmentation-fault, fgets, coredump

I am getting a segmentation fault exactly at this line:

```
while (fgets(line, MAX_LEN + 1, stream) != NULL) {

....

}
```

where MAX_LEN is 500, line is reading the current line, and stream is open through `fopen(filename, "r");`

I am reading lines from a file with a specific format and I get a segmentation fault (Core dumps) exactly at this line according to the debugger.

I made my code so that it ignores lines that do not match the scanf format.

Here is what I am implementing. Something close to it at least:

```
int main(int argc, int **argv) {
....
....
if (argc == 1) {
printf("enter file name: ");
scanf("%s", filename);
if (!(stream = fopen(filename, "r"))) {
    perror("Error message goes here.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


} else if (argc == 2) {
stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
 if (sream == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr, "error message", argv[1], errno));
   return EX_OSERR;
 }
}

while (fgets(line, MAX_LEN + 1, stream) != NULL) {
 if (sscanf(line, "%49[^@ ]@%49s -> %49[^@ ]@%49s", sender_username, sender_hostname,  receiver_username, receiver_hostname) != 4) {
  continue;
} else {

do work;

}
```

Comment: Any lines longer than 500 characters? How much memory is allocated to `line`?

Comment: Did you iniitalize `line` to point to allocated space?

Comment: is how I defined the MAX_LEN constant. Line is supposed to be a specific line according to a certain format from the text file that I am reading. You think I should make it longer?

Comment: line is defined as: line char[MAX_LEN + 1]; and the first time I use it I use it in the fgets() function

Comment: yes sorry thats right

Comment: Please show a small, complete, compilable example that exhibits the problem so we don't have to keep playing 20 questions.

Comment: for this project that I am working on, we are not supposed to use memory allocation. So any suggestions that don't use malloc() or calloc() would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok let me make an example.

Comment: No I did, look at my code posted below

Comment: Make it compilable and show what input you give and what errors you get. Basing on code you gave I can't answer your question.

Comment: These are important: **complete**, **compilable**, and **exhibits the problem**.  There's some detail that isn't making it to your example. You should be able to easily make your example fit the complete and compilable requirements (I did in 5 minutes).  Then all you need to do is make it crash in the same way that your real project does.  I'll bet that when you try making your example complete, compilable, and have the problem you'll have a bonus of actually finding out what the problem is.  If not, someone here will actually be able to.

Comment: @Michael Burr. I don't even know what the problem is in the first place to make a smaller version of this code and run it to crash in the same way as it does in the longer version. The problem is, my code works on smaller input files that it is trying to process, but for larger ones, it crashes.